# Why Visual Studio ask me to Find Source Code of SQLiteCommand.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I am using C# on Visual Studio 2015, developing a simply database utility with SQLite libaray "sqlite-netFx40-binary-x64-2010-1.0.99.0" downloaded from: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki.
The program works find, but the Visual Studio sometimes poped a browsing dialog out, prompting me to identify the source code of SQLite. But in fact I only downloaded the library. 
So I would like to ask: Why this happens? How to disable that?

[There is a screenshot about what I encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y3ok.png)

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047946/815938) answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code is not included in compiled assemblies. Instead the Visual Studio debugger uses other files (such as .PDB files) to find the source code. You have a situation where the debugger wants to display source code but cannot locate it on your machine. You are then prompted to locate the source by hand. This occurs e.g. when the debugger breaks on an exception in library code, or when you "step into" library code. For the latter situation you can enable the "Just My Code" debugger option. The debugger then steps over library code, even when using "step into". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(VS.80).aspx for details.